# How to create a transparent button which does not hide labels behind it in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, button, label, transparency

I am using vb.net and I am trying to create a transparent button which covers a label. The idea is that you can click this button to select the label as the one you are editing. The label can be visible or invisible so the user can see another label behind it at certain times, so just clicking the label doesn't work. I have set the flatstyle of the button to flat, and the backcolour to web > transparent. I know the button is transparent because you can still see a background that is behind everything. I also know the button is obscuring the text because if I place the button half over the label then I can still see the half that isn't covered. I'm completely at a loss, so any help will be appreciated. As I just set up this account I don't have enough reputation to post more than two links, so that explains the spaces.

EDIT:
The transparent buttons are over every square in the grid. I want to click the transparent button so that it feels like you are clicking the grid-square. Then the aim is to click a number on the pad next to it to edit that square. You should be able to see the "1"s that you can see in the picture without the buttons at all. I want to be able to have the buttons there so that you can still click them to select a cell, but I still want to see the numbers on the labels behind. So how do I make this happen?

How it should look (The button is deleted):
[image]

How it looks with the button:
[image]

How it looks with the button moved to half obscure user control:
[image]

Properties of my button (1 of 2):
[image]

Properties of my button (2 of 2):
[image]

Comment: Its not at all clear what the issue is - you did not actually ask a question.  There are lots of buttons there - what exactly is the problem?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Thanks, I have edited it to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: There is no real concept of one control being "behind" another one.  If they are in the same controls collection, they are siblings.  They can be behind or in front of another in terms of ZOrder, but when the Location overlaps that doesnt cause the effect you want.  You should still read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Is this winforms? web? wpf? something else I forgot to mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've described I don't see that you necessarily need to hide a button over a label. I would recommend that you don't overlap controls - especially if you are allowing the user to resize the form.

As a solution I would update the text of a selected button on a click event with the initial text in the button being empty (i.e. "").

Below is a winforms example that tries to replicate what you described:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsgJe.png

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _selButton As Button 'Current button selected
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        AddHandler btn1.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click
        AddHandler btn2.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click
        AddHandler btn3.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click
        AddHandler btn4.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click
        AddHandler btn5.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click
        AddHandler btn6.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click
        AddHandler btn7.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click           
        AddHandler btn8.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click
        AddHandler btn9.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click
        AddHandler btn0.Click, AddressOf UpdateText_Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateText_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim thisButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        If (_selButton IsNot Nothing) Then
            _selButton.Text = thisButton.Text
            _selButton.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub matrixbtn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles matrixbtn1.Click
        _selButton = matrixbtn
        matrixbtn1.BackColor = Color.Aqua
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a small panel, and customize its properties. Double click it. You will be taken to the code section to code for the click event of a panel. No need to use a button at all. You can use **ANY** control in VB like a button. This includes labels, pictureboxes, groupboxes, and even the form itself. All have a click event you can use. Just select it form the dropdown event menu:
[image: The dropdown event menu.]

This is its expanded form:

[image: As you can see, lots of options. Look through and explore them.]

Note that `Load` means what happens on startup. Code here what happens right when the form opens.